# SQL Add a Column using Left Join in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, left-join

I have a table where I'm looking to add a column `IS_TRUE` based on another table with a where clause.

I.e: I have a table called `Employee` and I have another table named `Manager`, now I want to insert/add `IS_True` column in table `Employee` based on:

```
 A.ID = B.ID where ((A.Name Is Not Null) and (B.ID is null))
```

Looking for a single view which does this with out duplicating the data in table `Employee`.

Table `Employee`

```
ID|Name|Salary
 1|B   |333
 3|B   |333
 4|B   |333
 1|B   |333
```

Table `Manager`

```
ID  |Name
 1  |A
 3  |B
 4  |B
Null|A
```

Results:

```
ID|Name|Salary|IS_True
 1|B   |333   |YES
 3|B   |333   |NO
 4|B   |333   |NO
 1|B   |333   |YES
```

Comment: Maybe expand your question with a few rows of sample data and expected results?

Comment: Can you explain how you got the data as "Yes" in your Results table?
Your condition:  A.ID = B.ID where ((A.Name Is Not Null) and (B.ID is null))
It's not possible that A.ID = B.ID and B.ID is null, even if A.ID is null.

Comment: Nithin, the logic i gave will not work when the A.ID and B.ID is unique but works when we have duplicates.. to know if the condition is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT    a.*, 
          CASE WHEN a.name IS NOT NULL AND b.id IS NULL 
               THEN 'YES' 
               ELSE 'NO' 
          END AS is_true
FROM      employee a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM manager) b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Hi Mureinik, this is actually creating duplicates, i want only the records from employee table to get updated.

Comment: @SAK updated my query to use `distinct` - should solve it - please try?

Answer (score 0):

try this: add a where clause with the join

```
SELECT    a.*, 
          CASE WHEN a.name IS NOT NULL AND b.id IS NULL 
               THEN 'YES' 
               ELSE 'NO' 
          END AS is_true
FROM      employee a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM manager) b ON a.id = b.id
where b.name is null
```